# Replace everything except first line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Configuring Xdebug"
ip=10.0.2.2
xdebug_config="/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini"

echo "IP for the xdebug to connect back: ${ip}"
echo "Xdebug Configuration path: ${xdebug_config}"
echo "Port for the Xdebug to connect back: ${XDEBUG_PORT}"
echo "Optimize for ${IDE} ide"

if [ $IDE=='atom' ]; then
  echo "Configuring xdebug for ATOM ide"
  config="xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=${ip}
xdebug.remote_port = ${XDEBUG_PORT}
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log"
 # replace the file in $xdebug_config var except first line
fi
```

What I want is to replace the first line in the file mentioned in `$xdebug_config` variable **EXCEPT** the first line. For example if the file is:

```
line 1
line 2
somethig else
lalala
```

I want to get converted like that:

```
line 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=${ip}
xdebug.remote_port = ${XDEBUG_PORT}
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log
```

How I can achieve that?

## Edit 1

As requested on the comments the `$xdebug_config` can contain theese possible values:

```
 /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini
 /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/xdebug.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

Generally it will be in the following format:

```
 /etc/php/^number^.^number^/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

## Edit 2

I perfected the shell script in order to be more clear.

Comment: Would it be possible that you include part of the file `$xdebug_config` in the question? This will make things much clearer. Currently, what you want is not clear, you had mentioned in the question `What I want is to replace the first line in the file mentioned in $xdebug_config variable EXCEPT the first line.` this is completely unclear.

Comment: Could you not just take the first line using `head -n1` and then write out the rest according to what you want?

Comment: take care: this will **always** be true: `[ $IDE=='atom' ]` -- paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a HERE doc?

```
line1=$(head -1 "$1")
cat <<EORL >"$1"
${line1}
this is line2
how about this for line3?
let's do another line!
moving on to the next line
Wait!  There's more???
EORL

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace a file's contents with arbitrary known data, but preserve the first line, you can do something like:

```
oldfile="/path/to/original/file"
newfile="$(mktemp)"
head -n1 "$oldfile" > "$newfile"
cat << EOF >> "$newfile"
Hey, all of these lines?
The lines after "cat"?
All of these lines up to and excluding the next line will be written.
EOF
mv "$oldfile" "${oldfile}.old"
mv "$newfile" "$oldfile"
```

The advantage of crafting a new file and moving it into place after it's fully composed is that you can keep the last version in case you need to roll back.

If you have no interest in doing this, you can just blow the old file away, but you can't read from and write to it in the same operation, so something like this will work:

```
header="$(head -n1 /path/to/file)"
echo "$header" > /path/to/file
cat << EOF >> /path/to/file
Hey, all of these lines?
The lines after "cat"?
All of these lines up to and excluding the next line will be written.
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write

```
{ sed 1q "$xdebug_config"; echo "$config"; } | sponge "$xdebug_config"
```

[`sponge`](https://manpage.me/?q=sponge) is in the `moreutils` package. If you don't want to install that:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
{ sed 1q "$xdebug_config"; echo "$config"; } > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$xdebug_config"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as  like this :

```
tempd=$(mktemp -d);printf '%s\n' "$config" > "$tempd/config"
sed -i -e "r $tempd/config" -e q "$xdebug_config"
rm -rf "$tempd"
```